# change the registration point when using Bitmapdata.draw?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movieclip on stage that I draw into a bitmap, how do I change the registration point, the code below produces bitmap with half chopped off:

```
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height, true, 0x00FFFFFF);
        var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.translate(0, -mc.height/2);
        bitmapData.draw(mc, matrix);

        var bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
        addChild(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this excellent article from Mike Chambers on bitmapData.hitTest and how to check for collisions after transformations have been made to the display objects, all sorted now:
http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/200...ion-detection/